# Getting data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase I have checked code many times but when it runs the app crashes and return to the main activity

```
void getdata()
{
    String string;
     DatabaseReference mDatabase;
     FirebaseAuth mAuth;
     FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
     mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
     firebaseDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
     string=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();        
   mDatabase=firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child(string);
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            email=dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
            name=dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            tvHeaderName.setText(email);
            tvFooterName.setText(name);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(Home.this,databaseError.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

It should set email and name on

```
tvHeaderName.setText(email);

tvFooterName.setText(name);
```

NOTE: I had declared the `tvFooterName` and `tvHeaderName` globally;

Comment: can you show your crash log ??

Comment: As @Niceumang says, please add the crash logs. Also, where do you initialize `tvFooterName` and `tvHeaderName`?

Comment: change the name of your variable here `String string;`

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please also responde with @AlexMamo